# returnPressed event error: 'myApp' object has no attribute 'send_box'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I Have the above code... I need to add the `returnPressed()` event to the send_box `QLineEdit()`, but i'm getting an error below:

> self.send_box.returnPressed.connect(self.sendData) AttributeError:
>   'myApp' object has no attribute 'send_box'

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLineEdit, QFileDialog, QInputDialog, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.Qt import QPushButton, QTextEdit


class myApp (QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(200,100,400,580)
        self.setWindowTitle('My Application')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))

        main_text       =       QTextEdit(self)
        send_box        =       QLineEdit(self)

        # ReturnedPressed Event code here 
        self.send_box.returnPressed.connect(self.sendData)

        connect_btn     =       QPushButton('Connect', self)
        browse_btn      =       QPushButton('Browse', self)


        ip_add_box      =       QLineEdit(self)
        port_box        =       QLineEdit(self)

        main_text.setGeometry(25, 30, 360, 350)
        send_box.setGeometry(25, 400, 360, 60)
        ip_add_box.setGeometry(25, 530, 150, 30)
        port_box.setGeometry(180, 530, 90,30)
        connect_btn.setGeometry(25, 500, 70, 25)
        browse_btn.setGeometry(100,500,70,25)



        self.show()

    def sendData(self):
        self.main_text.append( self.send_box.text() )
        self.send_box.clear() 


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = myApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `send_box` to `self.send_box` and `main_text` to `self.main_text`

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLineEdit, QFileDialog, QInputDialog, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.Qt import QPushButton, QTextEdit


class myApp (QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(200,100,400,580)
        self.setWindowTitle('My Application')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))

        self.main_text       =       QTextEdit(self)
        self.send_box        =       QLineEdit(self)
        # ReturnedPressed Event code here 
        self.send_box.returnPressed.connect(self.sendData)

        connect_btn     =       QPushButton('Connect', self)
        browse_btn      =       QPushButton('Browse', self)


        ip_add_box      =       QLineEdit(self)
        port_box        =       QLineEdit(self)

        self.main_text.setGeometry(25, 30, 360, 350)
        self.send_box.setGeometry(25, 400, 360, 60)
        ip_add_box.setGeometry(25, 530, 150, 30)
        port_box.setGeometry(180, 530, 90,30)
        connect_btn.setGeometry(25, 500, 70, 25)
        browse_btn.setGeometry(100,500,70,25)

    def sendData(self):
        self.main_text.append( self.send_box.text() )
        self.send_box.clear() 


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = myApp()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks man. I fixed that earlier and it worked. 

Though i still need help on pyqt5 socket programming... I can make a socket between two PCs using python console but have no clue on PyQt5

Comment: @Sabawoon If you already solved the problem, you should publish your post with the solution

Comment: I'm pretty new to stackoverflow and i just commented above you... i didn't know i can answer or post my answer myself.

Answer (score -1):

the line of code you have to call your method looks incorrect

change the line

```
 self.send_box.returnPressed.connect(self.sendData)
```

to

```
self.send_box.clicked.connect(self.sendData)
```

also if you want to send parms with the call you can do that also by using a lambda

```
self.send_box.clicked.connect(lambda: self.sendData(parm1,parm2))
```

Comment: I don't want the .clicked() event because it's a textbox i just needs to press enter to send the text from the QLineEdit to the QTextEdit

Comment: Problem fixed with the following. Thanks though

        self.main_text  =       QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        self.send_box   =       QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.send_box.returnPressed.connect(self.sendData)
        connect_btn     =       QtWidgets.QPushButton('Connect')
        browse_btn      =       QtWidgets.QPushButton('Browse')
        ip_add_box      =       QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        port_box        =       QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)